# Is it necessary to use triggers in CUSTOM_AUTH of AWS cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-cognito, custom-authentication

I want to create OTP based authentication using AWS cognito (CUSTOM_AUTH), all resources I saw were having 3 triggers(defineauth, createauth etc). Can I implement custom auth without using them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need all three. The first (Define Auth Challenge) lets you define the cognito auth statemachine execution (can include built in challenges). The second (Create Auth Challenge) sets up the challenge and defines the values to check against. The last (Verify Auth Challenge Response) lets you perform tests against the response and define whether the challenge succeeded. That gets passed back into the state machine which calls back to the first handler (Define Auth Challenge) which is where you can declare whether the user successfully authenticated.

Amazon has some examples of their own. I've seen a few random tutorials post flows that have security flaws so I'd stick with AWS for this.

[Email OTP example can be found here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/implementing-passwordless-email-authentication-with-amazon-cognito/).

Comment: Can I use normal flask methods instead of triggers ? I want cognito to store my OTP and I want to use that OTP later in my flask code to verify

Comment: You mean store the OTP as a user attribute? There's nothing stopping you but that is essentially a plaintext password in your user database... not secure at all.